# How to negate (change sign) of the floating point elements in a __m128 type variable?

Tags: c, x86, vectorization, sse, simd

Is there any single instruction or function that can [invert the sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse) of every float inside a __m128?
i.e. `a = r0:r1:r2:r3 ===> a = -r0:-r1:-r2:-r3`?

I know this can be done by `_mm_sub_ps(_mm_set1_ps(0.0),a)`, but isn't it potentially slow since `_mm_set1_ps(0.0)` is a multi-instruction function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flipping sign on packed SSE floats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361132/flipping-sign-on-packed-sse-floats)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In practice your compiler should do a good job of generating the constant vector for 0.0. It will probably just use `_mm_xor_ps`, and if your code is in a loop it should hoist the constant generation out of the loop anyway. So, bottom line, use your original idea of:

```
v = _mm_sub_ps(_mm_set1_ps(0.0), v);
```

or another common trick, which is:

```
v = _mm_xor_ps(v, _mm_set1_ps(-0.0));
```

which just flips the sign bits instead of doing a subtraction (not quite as safe as the first method, since it doesn't do the right thing with NaNs, but may be more efficient in some cases).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `xor` is fine with NaN.  The sign-bit in a NaN has don't-care status, so all NaNs stay as NaNs, and all non-NaNs stay non-NaN.  Quiet vs. signalling NaN is indicated by the highest bit of the mantissa (not the highest bit of the whole float).  Using `xor` is usually best.  On AMD, where `xorps` runs in the integer domain and thus has a bypass delay to/from FP math instructions, it's still about the same latency as 5c `subps`.

Comment: Loading the `-0.0` constant from memory could cache-miss, though.  Compilers don't like to [generate constants on the fly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085059/what-are-the-best-instruction-sequences-to-generate-vector-constants-on-the-fly) if it takes more than one insn (`xorps same,same` or `pcmpeqw same,same` (all-ones)).  This one just takes [`pcmpeqw xmm7,xmm7` / `pslld xmm7, 31`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32422471/224132)  (see that link for SSE absolute value: ANDN with that mask, or AND with its inverse)

Comment: Can't `_mm_set1_ps(0.0)` be replaced with `_mm_setzero_ps()`?

Comment: @MarcinPoliczek: yes, use whichever you prefer - the same code will be generated by the compiler in either case.

Comment: Is there any way handle 0x80000000 (i.e -2147483648). I am expecting 2147483647 as result

Comment: Stick with `_mm_setzero_ps()` - it's really a 'synthetic' intrinsic that doesn't have an exact correspondence to a particular instruction. That means it conveys a *semantic* requirement in a modern compiler, and can often lead to more efficient code based on local code generation.

Comment: @BrettHale: the [same code will be generated in either case](https://godbolt.org/z/eExWhch6f), so it’s more a matter of style or personal preference.