# Is there a way to flip the sign bit of 32 bit float with xor?

Tags: assembly, x86, simd

I'm trying to flip the sign bit of the least significant float inside of xmm0. I've tried to convert -0 into another xmm register and xor it with xmm0. Unfortunately, I've achieved to flip the sign though the value of my float is gone. Is there a way to use `xorps` in asm in order to flip the sign bit? I've also seen some posts on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083997/how-to-negate-change-sign-of-the-floating-point-elements-in-a-m128-type-vari?lq=1) exactly doing that but in c.

```
# xmm0 contains 4 floats
# goal is to flip the sign of the least significant one
mov eax, -0
cvtsi2ss xmm1, eax
xorps    xmm0, xmm1
```

Comment: `mov eax, 0x80000000; movd xmm1, eax; xorps xmm0, xmm1`

Comment: @Jester Many thanks! That was quick. I've tried something similar but that didn't work out as I had expect it. Unfortunately, I can't accept your solution.

Comment: FYI: -0 and 0 are the same 2's complement integer number. -0.0 and 0.0 are different floating point numbers. So `mov eax, -0` is equivalent to `mov eax, 0`

Comment: @Jester Or place `0x80000000` in memory and reference it with a memory operand.

Comment: Does anyone of you might answer my question really quick. Then I can mark it as done. The solution mentioned by @Jester, pcarter or fuz did fit to my problem, so just copy and paste it.

Comment: @Jester: If you're going to generate it on the fly, I'd tend to go for `pcmpeqd xmm1,xmm1` / `pslld xmm1, 31` unless you specifically want to leave the high elements unmodified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To flip the sign bit of the least significant float inside of xmm0 the solution looks like what Jester posted in the comment section of my question:

```
mov eax, 0x80000000
movd xmm1, eax
xorps xmm0, xmm1
```

(credits to Jester and everyone else who helped me. I just wanted to mark this topic as done)

Comment: If you're going to avoid loading a constant from memory, `pcmpeqd xmm1,xmm1` / `pslld xmm1, 31` about as efficient to materialize a vector of `set1(-0.0)`. ([What are the best instruction sequences to generate vector constants on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35085059)).  Both ways are 9 bytes of code, though, before the `xorps`.  Only difference is which back-end ports the uops can run on.  `movd` is limited to one port on Intel (port 5), `pcmpeqd` and `pslld` can each run on at least 2 ports on most CPUs.  So the best choice depends on surrounding code. movd latency prob. irrelevant.